# Convert python 2 code to 3 in PyCharm

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a large ML project in python 2 code and I just started using PyCharm as an IDE. I'm currently using WinPython 3.4 and I'd preferably like to do everything in python 3 instead of continue using legacy 2. When I cloned the project from git a popup in pycharm came up that was something along the lines of converting the code to 3 from 2 but I didn`t really think about it and exited it. How do I convert it?

Comment: `2to3.py` will convert 80% of 80% of scripts (about).

Comment: try https://python2to3.com/ for single file scripts

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I found a way in **Pycharm** IDE to convert file from v2 to v3 using 2to3 tool.

I applied in pycharm comunity edition v 2016.2.3 in windows environment.

- click **terminal** in status bar
  Now, you are in shell command, in the root of your project.
- type the command (to convert myfile.py):

```
2to3 myfile.py -w
```

The tool modifies the code of the file, and your IDE is reflected with the changes.

To modify all your files in the folder, type the command

```
2to3 . -w
```

The option `-w` to actually write the changes. 
For more details write:

```
2to3 -h
```

Comment: You want 3to2 for that. Try to install 3to2 using pip or from within pycharm.

Comment: Pycharm community 2018.xxx here. You need to install 2to3 separately. `pip install 2to3` (or at least it's not in the standard venv)

Answer (score 3):

Goto the folder where your python2script.py is existing in command line,

then execute the command:

```
python C:/python/Tools/scripts/2to3.py -w python2script.py
```

you can see that your python2scipt.py is updated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to convert your python script from version-2 to version-3, you can simply use 2to3 utility.

On linux terminal -

```
$ 2to3 my_file.py              # shows output only on terminal
```

or

```
$ 2to3 -w my_file.py           # overwrites the file with python-3 code
```

where my_file.py is the file which you want to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods to convert python 2.X.X to python 3.X.X

1. **Using Web-application**

I develop a web application to convert python 2.x.x code to python 3.x.x.
Here is the [Automatic Python 2 to 3 converter](https://360techexplorer.com/tools/python-2-to-3-converter/).

Note: This web app is FREE and using this `2to3` python library.

---

2. **Using 2to3 library, *Read the [doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html).***

Install 2to3 library

```
pip install 2to3
```

Convert myfile.py

```
2to3 myfile.py
```

This commends create a new file that contains your Python 3 code.

If you want to overwrite the myfile.py use -w argument like 2to3 myfile.py -w. Read the docs for more arguments.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [script](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) included with Python, usually at `[Python Root]/Tools/Scripts/2to3.py`.  You can run that script on a python file (or directory of python files) and it will handle a lot of the conversions, at least for changes in the standard library.

It gets a little more complicated if your project uses other 3rd party libraries.  It's possible the API's for those changed during the 2-to-3 transition, and the `2to3.py` script will not know about those api changes.  Your best bet is to run the conversion script, and then manually make any other changes that are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Before anything I would save a backup copy of your Python 2 file first.

You can then try to convert the code using the "2to3" Automated Python 2 to 3 code translation tool which is built into Python via the Standard Library.
Details on usage can be found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#

You also have the choice between two tools to port your code automatically: Modernize and Futurize. Check them out below.

Modernize --> https://python-modernize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Futurize --> http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html

In terms of Pycharm, I have not seen / don't know of any specialized tool within the IDE that converts code from Python 2 to Python 3. I'd stick to the 3 tools above.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to use it within the PyCharm IDE, you can add it as an **external tool**:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Tools` -> `External Tools` and press the `+` button.

A new window opens, give a name to your tool (*e.g.* 2to3) and a description.

In `Program` add the path to the script, if you use Linux, it should be located in `/usr/bin/2to3-2.7`

In the `Arguments` line, add `$FileName$` if you want your tool to work for the current open file, or `.` on the current directory, and `-w` to apply the changes as seen in the other replies.

Add `$FileDir$` in the `Working directory` line.

Press OK and in an open file, go to `Tools` -> `External Tools` -> `2to3` to run the script.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this free online tool for quickly converting few files

https://python2to3.com/