# Can PyCharm highlight Python 2 specific code to enable migration?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working with a large Python 2 code base, which should be prepared to move to Python 3 some time in the future.

I was wondering if there are any ways in PyCharm to highlight parts, which would not run in Python 3, e.g. usages of

```
print 'abc'
```

should be highlighted.

I'm not looking for an automated way to transform the code, but I just want to get aware of problematic areas as a first step.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but the `2to3` tool that comes with Python can be used to give you a list of diffs that you can then go through. (I know how to iterate those diffs from emacs python-mode, but not through PyCharm… and I'm guessing PyCharm may actually have its own built-in tool instead.)

Comment: You can setup multiple different version `virtualenv` and change the Project Interpreter accordingly.

Comment: After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37891188/), it looks like people aren't using PyCharm features to do this, just running `2to3` manually. While we're at it, if you want to maintain dual-version code for a while, you should look at using [`modernize`](https://pypi.org/project/modernize/), probably with [`six`](https://pypi.org/project/six/), instead of `2to3`.

Comment: Also see [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/920962/), which may or may not be relevant here. From a quick search I found [this help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html), but I'm not sure where to find more details on what it checks.

Comment: Why is someone down-voting my question? I can't change the interpreter in PyCharm as I still need to run the code in Py2. Also, I want to get aware of incompatible code while writing code so that I (and my fellow colleagues) don't add more incompatible code. So something like 2to3 is not helpful in that.

Comment: @abarnert The question on SuperUser you pointed to is the correct answer. That's what I was looking for!

Comment: @Sebi Something like `2to3` really is helpful; it just isn't a complete answer in itself. I've used it (and `modernize`) extensively for exactly the problem you're facing. Don't auto-apply the changes; generate diffs. Then you need to set things up so that you can step through the diffs it suggests in your editor. Ideally, you mark any irrelevant diffs to be skipped next time, and, once you've fixed or marked every diff, you can even use it as a commit hook. If PyCharm offers a better solution that makes this all pointless, that's great, but otherwise, I wouldn't dismiss it.

Comment: @Sebi As for why your question is being downvoted—well, it's only 1 vote over 24 hours, so I wouldn't worry too much. But my guess? If I hadn't tried to search for the answer myself, I might have assumed that either this was a clearly documented and easy to find feature in PyCharm, or that it didn't exist. Of course after searching and only finding an answer that may be relevant on SU, I know that's not true. But people only have so much time available, so not everyone researches before guessing how much research you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is posted on SuperUser here: https://superuser.com/a/1070519/196371

PyCharm has an inspection to highlight code, which wouldn't work in different Python versions. They promote it as a tool to help maintainers of libraries to write multi-version compatible code.

This inspection is off by default. To turn it on, go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python and check "Code compatibility inspection". On the right pane, you can also tick the languages your code should be compatible with.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to File > Settings > Project: (Project Name) > Project Interpreter

Change this to the Python3 version you are going to be using. The built in error catching (right side color coding with highlighted text) should catch Python3 syntax errors.

Note: this will catch blatant errors, but like most automated solutions, this will not catch things like opening text files in 'rb' mode in Python2 which worked fine, but would not work as intended in python3

Comment: This will only catch things that are a `SyntaxError` or other statically-detectable error in Python 3, not things that are valid code but do the wrong this in 3.x. So I'm not sure it's sufficient for the OP's use.

Comment: @abarnert I'd just added a note about that, although his exact question was, "Things that won't run in Python3" which are mostly going to be syntactical errors. Most things this won't catch are going to be unintended behaviors, but it'll "run"

Comment: Yeah, I suppose we need to wait for the OP to tell us exactly what he's looking for before knowing whether this is sufficient, and now that the answer explains the limitations, there's no risk of misleading the OP or anyone else who comes along with a similar question.

Comment: This is not working as I still need to run my code and it would hinder my workflow if I would need to switch back and forth. However, @abarnert pointed already to this https://superuser.com/a/1070519/196371 answer, which also works in my situation!